# Asyncio and Threading working differently on linux and windows 10

Tags: python, linux, discord.py, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a Discord bot and I'm hosting it on a Raspberry Pi. The bot continuously scrapes a website looking for changes and when found sends a message to my Discord server. After that, the bot continues to look for changes on the site. The code I currently have works perfectly on my Windows 10 machine, but the same code, when executed on the Pi doesn't do the same thing. The version of Python on Windows is 3.10.8 and on linux is 3.9.2. Code below (I ommitted a lot of the logic indicated by `...`, but the asyncio and threading stuff is all here).

```py
class Bot:
    def __init__(self, client, loop):
        self.client = client
        self.loop = loop
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        
        @self.client.event
        async def on_ready():
            threading.Thread(target=self.runWaiter).start()
            print('Started...')
            ...

    def runWaiter(self):
        print('started runWaiter')
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.waiter(), self.loop).result()
        self.loop.run_forever()
    
    async def waiter(self):
        print('started waiter')
        while True:
            updated = self.checkForUpdates()
            while updated == []:
                updated = self.checkForUpdates()
                if updated == []:
                    print('checking')
                    await asyncio.sleep(5) # in production will be 60 seconds, but for fast testing is 5 seconds
            ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting...')
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    client = discord.Client(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='for changes'), loop=loop, intents=discord.Intents.all())
    bot = Bot(client, loop)

    ... # code that makes sure the pi is connected to the internet before running the bot, essentialy trying to connect to google.com

    bot.client.run(TOKEN)
```

It's important to note that the bot responds to commands when run either on Windows or Linux, but the scraping and important stuff doesn't work on Linux.

Console output on Windows machine:

```
Starting...
started runWaiter
Started...
started waiter
checking
checking
...
```

Console output on Pi (Linux):

```
Starting...
2022-10-31 17:05:18 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-10-31 17:05:19 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: df693341c2f4bbe4372afd70b5c8fefe).
started runWaiter
Started...
```

I tried looking into Python version differences and such, but didn't get far.
It seems that the `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.waiter(), self.loop).result()` is where the problem happens, since the `waiter` function isn't even being called.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need threading?

Comment: why are you using threading here?

Comment: When I first made this bot, my friend helped me with the threading and asyncio stuff since I had never really used those modules. The first version of the bot worked on the pi with this exact code and the only reason why I had to remake it is because the site I was scraping shut down. My goal here is to have a Discord bot that accepts commands in a text channel, and have the scraping and checking for updates happen in the background.